# Scala - how to use variables in a multi-line string literal

Tags: scala, gatling, string-interpolation

I want to call value of '**myActionID**' variable. How do I do that?
If i pass static value like "actionId":1368201 to myActionID then it works, but If I use "actionId" : ${actionIdd} it gives error.

Here's the relevant code:

```
class LaunchWorkflow_Act extends Simulation {

    val scenarioRepeatCount = 1
    val userCount = 1
    val myActionID = "13682002351"
    
    val scn = scenario("LaunchMyFile")
        .repeat (scenarioRepeatCount) {
            exec(session => session.set("counter", (globalVar.getAndIncrement+" "+timeStamp.toString())))
            .exec(http("LaunchRequest")
            .post("""/api/test""")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .body(StringBody(
                """{    "actionId": ${myActionID} ,
                "jConfig": "{\"wflow\":[{\"Wflow\":{\"id\": \"13500145349\"},\"inherit-variables\": true,\"workflow-context-variable\": [{\"variable-name\": \"externalFilePath\",\"variable-value\": \"/var/nem/nem/media/mount/assets/Test.mp4\"},{\"variable-name\": \"Name\",\"variable-value\": \"${counter}\"}]}]}"
                }""")))

            .pause(pause) 

        }
    }

setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(userCount))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Everything works fine If I put value 13682002351 instead of myActionID. While executing this script in Gatling I am Getting this error

> ERROR i.g.http.action.HttpRequestAction - 'httpRequest-3' failed to
> execute: No attribute named 'myActionID' is defined

Comment: Try: `"actionId": ${myActionID}`

Comment: @antikantian: Tried with your comment but error shows " No attribute named 'myActionID' is defined"

Answer (score 16):

Scala has various mechanisms for String Interpolation (see [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)), which can be used to embed variables in strings. All of them can be used in conjunction with the triple quotes `"""` used to create multi-line strings.

In this case, you can use:

```
val counter = 12
val myActionID = "13682002351"
val str = s"""{    
                "actionId": $myActionID ,
                "jConfig": "{\"wflow\":[{\"Wflow\":{\"id\": \"13500145349\"},\"inherit-variables\": true,\"workflow-context-variable\": [{\"variable-name\": \"externalFilePath\",\"variable-value\": \"/var/nem/nem/media/mount/assets/Test.mp4\"},{\"variable-name\": \"Name\",\"variable-value\": \"${counter}\"}]}]}"
              }"""
```

Notice the `s` prepended to the string literal, and the dollar sign prepended to the variable names.

Comment: I am not able to compile the code after adding the line you mentioned val  str = s"""...."""

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives error status.find.in(200,304,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209), b 1 (100.0%) ut actually found 400.
Any other way?? have tried with almost all the combinations,
"actionId": $actionIdD, "actionId": ${actionIdD}, "actionId: $actionIdD", "actionId":  + actionIdD, s"actionId: $actionIdD", s"actionId": $actionIdD
but gives the same error

Comment: Try testing the string creation separately from the Gatling request - you might be looking at the wrong place. The code I pasted executes successfully in Scala REPL and inserts the value of `myActionID` - I can't vouch for anything else (correctness of json, any other code) as there's not enough context, and your error might be coming from there...

Comment: I think this is not server side or Json related issue, as It works when I pass 13682002351 as actionID in .body, while gives error when use variable name.

Comment: did you add the `s` before the _triple-quote_ sign (not before the single-quote encapsulating actionId)?? I can't see how this can fail, the code pasted above works in REPL and produces a string starting with `{ "actionId": 13682002351 , "jConfig":`...

Comment: I have posted code in answer with list of errors in "I did this, val actionId = "1368225424501" with errors. Can you please check. Thanks :-)

Comment: if I use your code val str = s"""{ "actionId": $myActionID ,...}
then it shows ${counter} error as it is declared in exec(session => session.set("counter",...) and we are calling it before declaration, so I am not able to call that 'str' in '.body'. any other solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

Using **S interpolated String** we can do this easily:

```
 s"""Hello Word , Welcome Back!
      How are you doing ${userName}"""
```